# Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.5

I tried to run composer update on laravel5.5 but along the running I encountered this message

when it reached this line

```
@php artisan package:discover
```

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException] The
>   process "'/usr/bin/php7.3' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d
>   disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='-1' artisan package:discover"
>   exceeded the timeout of 2000 seconds.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked the internet connection? Have you checked for updates of any installed package?